# How to know the complete list of providers and available extensions in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-api-management, azure-resource-manager

I would like to know where we can find the list of all the available providers and the related extensions for resources that can be defined in ARM template

Regards
Parimi.

Answer (score 2):

[Resource Manager providers, regions, API versions and schemas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/) might be what you're looking for. This includes sections on all of the resource providers and in each of those sections gives links to the REST API docs, schema, and related quickstart templates

Comment: I have gone through that link, but it doesn't cover the extensions that are available for the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who spends time with Resource Manager would dearly love to have exactly that! Unfortunately it doesn't exist. What [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/) does exist is sparse to the point that it is beginner only stuff

Instead we are left picking through [Resource Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates), [The Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) and [assorted](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) - [Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) - [Code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli) to try to figure out what pieces fit where.

oh and there's a [Rest API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs) and [Resource Template Schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas) which are very useful.

(for a solution that talks about revenues in the billions, you'd think they could afford to pay a couple of tech writers!)